# Locating XML node by child node value inside of it, and changing another value

Tags: c#, xml

Three part question.

Is it possible to locate a specific XML node by a child inside of it to retrieve other children of the parent? Example:

```
<House>
    <Kitchen>
        <Appliance>
            <Name>Refrigerator</Name>
            <Brand>Maytag</Brand>
            <Model>F2039-39</Model>
        </Appliance>
        <Appliance>
            <Name>Toaster</Name>
            <Brand>Black and Decker</Brand>
            <Model>B8d-k30</Model>
        </Appliance>
    </Kitchen>
</House>
```

So for this, I would like to locate the appropriate Appliance node by searching for "Refrigerator" or "Toaster", and retrieve the brand from it.

The second part of this question is this: Is this a stupid way to do it? Would using an attribute in the Appliance tag make this a lot easier? If so, how would I locate it that way?

As for the third part, once I locate the Appliance, how would I go about changing say, the Model, of that particular appliance?

Comment: The XML looks fine, I'd only suggest one change.  I would add a `<Appliances>` tag around the list of `<Appliance>` tags.  This way if you decide to add more below the `<Kitchen>` tag, its not a big mess.

Comment: SwDevMan, this was just an example. The actual XML file I'm working with is entirely different objects, and is of course formatted that way. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [XLinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195), you can perform this query fairly naturally:

```
// Given:
//   var xdoc = XDocument.Load(...);
//   string applianceName = "Toaster";

// Find the appliance node who has a sub-element <Name> matching the appliance
var app = xdoc.Root
              .Descendants("Appliance")
              .SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Element("Name") == applianceName);

// If we've found one and it matches, make a change
if (app != null)
{
    if (((string)app.Element("Model")).StartsWith("B8d-k30"))
    {
        app.Element("Model").Value = "B8d-k30 Mark II";
    }
}

xdoc.Save(@"output.xml"); // save changes back to the document
```

Comment: This is perfect, except I had to change e to o. Thank you. I'm still a serious Linq noob and have no idea how to use it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well if you are using XmlDocument

```
foreach(XmlNode applianceNode in 
          myDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Kitchen/Applicance[Name='Refrigerator']")
{
   XmlNode modelNode = applicianceNode.SelectSingleNode("Model").InnerText = SomeOtherValue;
}
```

if you made the name tag an attribute (applicanceName) it would make little difference to this.

```
foreach(XmlNode applianceNode in 
          myDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Kitchen/Applicance[@applianceName='Refrigerator']")
{
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string xml = @"<House>
    <Kitchen>
        <Appliance>
            <Name>Refrigerator</Name>
            <Brand>Maytag</Brand>
            <Model>F2039-39</Model>
        </Appliance>
        <Appliance>
            <Name>Toaster</Name>
            <Brand>Black and Decker</Brand>
            <Model>B8d-k30</Model>
        </Appliance>
    </Kitchen>
</House>";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    string newModel = "B8d-k45";

    var matchingElement = (from appliance in xdoc.Descendants("Appliance")
                           where appliance.Element("Name").Value == "Toaster"
                           select appliance).FirstOrDefault();

    if (matchingElement != null)
    {
        matchingElement.Element("Model").Value = newModel;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.
Yes, it's even simpler with XPath, and works completely without Linq:
Just use .. to get to the parent node (on the second thought, Linq will be easier when using "ordinalignorecase")

```
public static void CreateNewHouse()
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.XmlResolver = null;
    doc.Load(@"d:\House.xml");

    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode modelNode in doc.DocumentElement
.SelectNodes("/House/Kitchen/Appliance/Name[text()='Refrigerator']/../Model"))
    {
        modelNode.InnerText = "A New Value";
    }

    doc.Save(@"d:\MyHouse.xml");
}
```

MyHouse.xml:

```
<House>
  <Kitchen>
    <Appliance>
      <Name>Refrigerator</Name>
      <Brand>Maytag</Brand>
      <Model>A New Value</Model>
    </Appliance>
    <Appliance>
      <Name>Toaster</Name>
      <Brand>Black and Decker</Brand>
      <Model>B8d-k30</Model>
    </Appliance>
  </Kitchen>
</House>
```

If you need it case-insensitive, replace text() with this:

```
translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

(for ASCII/english-only) and of course change "Refrigerator" to lowercase ("refrigerator")

If the XML-document has a default-namespace, you need to supply it in Select*Node, e.g.

```
 xnImageTag.SelectSingleNode("./dft:Source", nsmgr);
```

where

```
System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = GetReportNamespaceManager(doc);

public static System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager GetReportNamespaceManager(System.Xml.XmlDocument doc)
{
    if (doc == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("doc");

    System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

    // <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

    if (doc.DocumentElement != null)
    {
        string strNamespace = doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
        System.Console.WriteLine(strNamespace);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("dft", strNamespace);
        return nsmgr;
    }

    nsmgr.AddNamespace("dft", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition");
    // nsmgr.AddNamespace("dft", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition");

    return nsmgr;
} // End Function GetReportNamespaceManager
```